# How to show I did search on old questions and can't find help before asking new question?

Tags: discussion, questions

My question [How to debug Drush command with xdebug in vscode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/225113/how-to-debug-drush-command-with-xdebug-in-vscode) has been marked as [duplicate] which really upset me.

In the question, I did mention I have studied the answer in similar question but it can't help. Sadly, it still be considered as duplicate. How to show moderators that I have enough knowledge to understand those answers?

Answer (score 3):

I maintain that it's a duplicate. We don't need a different question for getting xdebug working in every possible IDE or environment, we need the generic steps for all IDEs and environments, which we have. From there, each user can apply the knowledge to the software they've chosen to use, with whatever caveats/additional steps come with that decision. It will likely involve consulting the manual for said software.

However I'm not infallible, so if you really think that it's a different question, where are the details that show it? For your research, we have:

> I reviewed a lot of articles

With respect: so what? What did they say? What, specifically, did you try from these articles? What happened? What errors did you get? How do we know you didn't just follow the existing instructions incorrectly or make a typo etc? The methods outlined in the duplicate work with every other IDE, what does your research about your IDE tell you about this? You can't be the only one who's ever had trouble connecting this IDE to xdebug using CLI, what has your research into that told you? How do other people connect non-Drupal CLI projects to this IDE?

And so on.

And on to your ultimate question:

> Any help?

This isn't a help desk so no, unless there's a specific question, no help. If you ask a vague, generic question, and the same vague, generic question exists with good answers, closing it as a duplicate is the right thing to do.

If your question is sufficiently different, or the answers didn't help you, you need to be very specific about what steps you took to apply those solutions. That way people can spot if you've just done something obviously wrong, or if your question really does come into new territory.

So to answer your question directly:

> How to show moderators that I have enough knowledge to understand those answers?

Easy. Actually **show** it, by describing how you applied it, and why it didn't help solve the problem.

Comment: I have described what I have found and how my question is different to others.
"I reviewed a lot of articles about debugging Drush commands in PHPStorm with settings xdebug.idekey. In my experience, vscode simply ignores the xdebug.idekey value because it works with any value I set when I use it to debug the http request made from the browser."

Comment: I don't agree that you have, sorry

Comment: My ultimate question is in the title. I just don't want to ask again the same question. You quote "any help?" as my ultimate question is totally misleading.

Comment: It's not misleading, and it's hardly the focus of my answer, is it? Please read and digest the rest of it

Comment: I have considered that some of you may think it is a duplicate question, so I did explain my understanding on the answer from other questions. Probably you think it is not enough. But I don't think it can be considered a duplicate.

Comment: To me, I don't mind you think my question is too board to answer. But I don't think it is duplicate as you said.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's so broad that it's the same generic question that's covered elsewhere. Don't get too hung up on the wording

Comment: I think you have misunderstanding on it. As you pointed out that there is a generic answer can cover my question. But the question you mark as duplicate is specific for phpstorm. I can't see how it's answer is generic. If someone thought my question is too broad to answer, I feel free to provide more observation I have during investigation.

Comment: Nope, it's generic, as I've said many times now. The fact that phpstorm is mentioned once, in one answer, alongside the names of 2 other IDEs, should be enough to make that clear. I feel quite strongly that the misunderstanding does not come from me here.

Comment: You are too believe in yourself. I am pleased to discuss and help others and also myself to find out the missing puzzle of each question. But you are too confident to stop other asking question and never accepting other's mind. I can't see a way to keep contributing here. Probably I should ask question on drupal.org and GitHub. Thanks dude.

Comment: Or you could improve the question so it can be reopened. No point blaming others, it's an easy thing for you to do to make your question on topic. Don't try to make this about me, it's not. We don't want discussions, we want well-specified questions to begin with. Given the amount of time you've spent here, I find it hard to believe you don't already know that

Comment: I don't blame everyone. But it is not good to think that you know the basic php knowledge but others didn't. Sometimes asking a good question is not that easy. Indeed I don't know what I should provide when I was asking the question in the beginning. But it didn't mean that the one who ask question knows nothing.

Comment: I didn't say you did blame everyone, I didn't say you didn't have basic php knowledge. If you want to have a discussion, please make it about the things that have actually been said, not made up stuff. Asking a good question is hard, yes. The problems begin when you take anything on an anonymous Q+A site personally.

Comment: Fine. I can't see a common ground.

Comment: So you wont edit details of what you've tried into your question to make it more narrow and get it reopened? Then yes, I agree, there's  no common ground here

Comment: I did edit a lot.

Comment: But you still point blank refuse to edit in details of what steps you've taken to try to solve the problem. No one can help you if you refuse to help yourself.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of step you prefer. I can't get it. I did search a lot and find nothing wrong from my setting and installation apart from missing idekey setting in vscode. I did change nothing because it seems nothing relevant. Should I list out all links and the values I checked one by one? Is the settings post not enough?

Comment: The settings are probably irrelevant - you already said this process works fine for non-Drupal php CLI projects right, it's just drush specifically that causes you a problem - so that must be configured correctly, Drupal and drush don't need special settings for xdebug. In the marked duplicate there are several answers which would have yielded specific results when you attempted them. What were those results? It couldn't be nothing, you'll have seen error messages, notices, one of the steps won't have made sense in your environment, etc, etc, etc...that's the sort of detail you need in there

Comment: Nah. I didn't said the process works fine for non-Drupal php CLI. The working one is Drupal through apache. I will try to evaluate more what I tried but I don't think it will meet your criteria. At the end I probably give up it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I updated the question. And I would say that I did all solution from the marked duplicate and there is no any kind of message. Drush runs smoothly but the vscode can't detect the xdebug. I don't know what else I can copy or provide from my try.

Answer (score 0):

With al respect, but IMO the question "[How to debug Drush command with xdebug in vscode?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/225113/39516)" is ***NOT*** a duplicate.

However, have a look at the [timeline of this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/225113/timeline) (if you're not familiar with "timeline", you're missing something really interesting ...):

- [Timestamp 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/225113/timeline#review_91330): 2 ***reviewers*** voted to reopen (which got overruled by an unknown moderator via "invalidated"). BTW: 0 "leave closed" reviews.
- [Timestamp 2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/225113/timeline#review_91336): 1 ***reviewer*** voted to reopen (which got overruled by an unknown moderator via "invalidated"). BTW: 0 "leave closed" reviews.

So an improved version of your question could be something like "and how to make the moderators listen to those 3 reviewers (who voted to reopen) also?". Because for those who don't know, this is part of what's written in that yellow block to the right of the review queues:

> Drupal Answers is moderated by you.
>
> Help your fellow members learn to use the site and raise the quality of Q&A by ...

Really? If that's the case, then don't allow moderators to invalidate (twice!) the review process completed by some other users. Because each time they do so, is like saying to those reviewers "your vote doesn't count".

Comment: I am not sure what the point of this answer is other than to raise suspicions about nefarious moderator activity.  Moderators can't invalidate individual votes; that is system log there because something else in the timeline happened to make the votes go away.  I've stared at that timeline for ten minutes, and don't see suspicious behavior by anyone.  That question should still stay closed.  Currently, it is a "wall of code" question that just asks for help.

Comment: @mpdonadio It would be nice to use a version of English that does not require none-native English speaking users to go get a dictionary tool to look up the meaning of "nefarious". Apart from that: did you see that "***invalidated***" in that timeline? ... ***Twice*** ... in ***Red*** ... Where in the "help" pages (or whatever) is it documented what those "invalidated" things are about (what causes them, how to understand them, etc)? Or do you want me to describe around here how I "interpret" such "invalidated".

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was a common word.  I said **I SPENT TEN MINUTES STARING AT THE TIMELINE**, so yes I saw the invalidated lines.  In fact I said **Moderators can't invalidate individual votes**, so yes, I saw the invalidated messages.  I then went on to say that I looked at the whole timeline and didn't see suspicious behavior, so yes, I saw the invalidated messages.  Most things like that (details which can only be seen by a small audience), can be found in MSE posts and not the general help center.

Comment: And, again, please stop with the offhand accusations of moderator abuse.  If you think the moderators of this site are acting in appropriately, the please contact the CM team with your concerns.  They will look into the matter and contact the moderator team with their findings and advice.  Thank you.